# telnetlib read_until() Does Not Match Anything

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I am writing a Python script to parse some data from a remote telnet server on port 10001. Basically, when I type:

```
$ telnet <host> 10001
```

The terminal prints out:

```
Trying <host>...
Connected to static-<host>.nycmny.fios.verizon.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
# empty line for prompt
```

On the empty line in the comment that's where I should type commands like the following (`'\n'` stands for hitting return):

```
^Ai20101\n 
# server prints out data 
somedatalinehere
^]
# escape to telnet prompt like below
telnet> 
telnet> quit\n
connection closed.
# returns to local terminal prompt
```

However, when I do this in Python:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, 10001)
tn.read_until("\r\n", timeout=1)     # nothing matched, returns ''
tn.read_until("", timeout=1)         # nothing matched, returns ''
# thus 
tn.write("^Ai20101\n")
time.sleep(0.1)                      # wait 0.1s for next prompt
tn.write("^]")
time.sleep(0.1)
tn.write("quit\n")
tn.read_all()                        # This hangs as if connection wasn't closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using a child process from [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), which is much more flexible than telnetlib.

```
import pexpect
import time

child = pexpect.spawn('telnet <host> 10001')
child.sendcontrol('a')
child.send('i20101' + '\n')
```

Without any need to `read_until()`, this just worked.

Answer (score 1):

All that output before the actual command prompt (the `$` sign or something like that) is generated *by your own telnet client*, not by the server.

So try something like the following:

```
tn.read_until("$")
```

If this succeeds, this means you connected OK and may issue commands.

---

`read_all()` *should* 'hang'. Quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-objects):

> `Telnet.`**`read_all()`**
>
> Read all data until EOF; *block until connection closed*.

---

**Edit:**

Actually, you posted *no* server's response. All that stuff is, as I said before, generated by the client.

What does `# the prompt starts here` mean? I think it means that after all the output you're shown a command prompt, which looks something like that:

```
ForceBru @ iMac-ForceBru:~ $
```

So, you should read until this very line to ensure that the connection succeeded.

Comment: Thanks but I still got an empty string just the same. However I don't really understand your explanation. Can you elaborate? I know `$` is the prompt from my client, but then why should I read it with `read_until("$")`?

Comment: @PieOhPah, when you successfully connect to the server using mere `telnet` (no Python yet), you get back this prompt _from the server_. Copy it and paste instead of the dollar sign in my example.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to clarify what you're trying to say in relative to the response from the server I posted? It's exactly what the server replies, and there's no prompt like `$` anywhere.

Comment: Ok I'm getting clearer. However, where I place `# the prompt starts here` doesn't really have any prompt. Not even a `$`. Just blank line I can start typing command.